# How do I troubleshoot an unavailable internal website?

Tags: linux, http, web, dns, lamp

We have a range of websites hosted on our internal server and accessible from our internal network only.

E.g. one of them: http://your-ideas-matter

All of them suddenly stopped working, although no changes have been made to the server, application code, or databases.

Message in chrome is:

```
This site can’t be reached

your-ideas-matter refused to connect.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Steps I've taken so far:

- Pinging your-ideas-matter works and gets to the server fine
- vhosts file checked, no changes made since 2019 (sites stopped working last week).
- No errors reported in the Chrome console.
- I can still access our server (linux) directly via SSH, everything seems fine.
- Ran a df -h / -a - Used disk space is 92% (should be fine).
- Proxy settings have been checked - We aren't using a proxy.
- Server has been bounced.
- Tried other browsers. Same issue in IE and Firefox.

Our network team is reporting no issues with our Firewall etc.

So the question is, what is the troubleshooting directing I need to take?

Comment: After the first step, pinging the server, the second step should be to connect to the machine using SSH or RDP and see if the service is responding internally (curl http://localhost or similar). The third step is to check the logfiles for the application running on the server. In your case it would be the web server log files. Are you running Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc.? Once you know that, consult the documentation to locate where logging events are stored and look in the logs for errors.

Comment: Since server's IP is resolved (it can be pinged) this is not a DNS issue. When you access a server with ssh did you check web server logs? Did you check that web server is running?

Comment: Thanks All. Issue was Apache was down!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was Apache was down. A reference to a missing folder existed in httpd.conf. Commented this out and restarted apache.

Problem solved!